# Better way to Stretch web layout to the edges of the screen in CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm new to CSS and after some search, came to know different ways of stretching the web layout to the edges of the screen. I'm searching this topic for creating a responsive layout. I have adopted the two different ways which are:

```
body {
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    width:100%; 
    height:70px;
    padding:20px;
    background:#00CCCC;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/wPpk8/3/

and the second proper way is:

```
h2 { 
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
h2:before {
  right: 100%;
}
h2:after {
  left: 100%;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 9999px;
}
```

Here's its result: http://jsfiddle.net/wPpk8/2/

Please suggest which way one should adopt? Remember I've to create the entire web layout in this way.
Thanks!

Comment: Just showing CSS is not enough, show some HTML for both of the ways and also post two JSFiddle links to the code so it would be easier to change and see in action. By the look of it, the second way will not work for every case, while the first way would work for most.

Comment: this is more or less what you'd get: http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/wPpk8/ doesn't look correct.

Comment: what about the h2 tag? i don't get why you should use an h2 to "stretch" a layout

Comment: Thank @PhistucK for positive comment. Sorry for the trouble due to not posting some HTML. I edited my question with the link to jsfiddle. Please review both of the links for better understanding. Remember I just wanna create layout/bars stretched to the edges.

Comment: Thanks @omegaiori to you too for kind attention. Sorry for the trouble due to not posting some HTML. I edited my question with the link to jsfiddle. Please review both of the links for better understanding. I'm using h2 tag for header. This is just an example to show both of these ways to you, inshort this isn't the final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. A block element will be 100% wide by default, if you don't specify extra width using CSS. Here is an example based on your first solution which will give you the same results without complicating things:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

#header {
    padding:20px;
    background:#00CCCC;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wPpk8/4/

Comment: Actually (being a newbie in css world), I was at first assuming soemthing complex to create responsive themes. So was searching at that topic and found many easy solutions, everyone is doing in his own way. Two of those ways i used for learning/testing purposes are mentioned above. Now I was confused that when 100% width is simply possible as u said then what's about the second way? I was confused if the later one is the real solution and I'm doing something wrong so asked the question!

Comment: btw, this is not responsive, but liquid layout

Comment: Ok thanks @passatgt. gained half knowledge of css from stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

The method with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements in your example works just fine, though. There's nothing wrong with it, but it may be limiting.

Another approach is to use several parent elements for your content, or *inner-wrappers* as I like to call them.

### Inner wrappers:

HTML:

```
<div class="bar green">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bar blue">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar   { padding: 2em; }
.green { background: #c0ff33; }
.blue  { background: #c0ffee; }

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/tvDBc?editors=110) with this.

---

You can also use `calc` to push content out from its parent elements.

### An example with an image stretching to the edge of its container:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  padding: 2em;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% + 4em); /* add the left/right padding from the wrapper to the width of the image */
  
  position: relative;
  left: -2em; /* move the image to the edge of the wrapper */
}
```

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/Ahrci?editors=110) with this.

[Here's the browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for `calc`.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Nils Kaspersson for your attention & detailed response. Specially the second part of your solution, it's not my requirement rightnow but hope it will be very useful for me in future. Thanks for teaching me the new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

From those 2 better way is the first one. but of course there is no need to put 100% width to header when it's in wrapper which is also 100% width.

In responsive web design you should set width for some basic elements and not for every element in your html code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marcin, may I know the reason behind refering the first way to be better? Actually I'm confused as the 2nd way seems to be more proper & systematic but first one is easy & short one.
Thanks again for letting me know that setting width in any of the basic element is enough in this case. Sorry I haven't much reputation points to give you 1up otherwise you deserve

Comment: Because the second one is only complicating your CSS code. I am also learning Responsive Design at the moment. So far I've just created only one very simple site using RWD technique but already learned a lot. You should just practice to understand it and find many resources about this topic. You could look for example at this tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Comment: Okk Thanks again mate! Yeah I'm learning & found various ways for responsive design whereas I was trying to finalize and adopt any one of these. BTW Enjoying learning css, hope u'll too

Comment: went throught the link provided in the last comment. Really nice! Thanks @Marcin Nabialek :)